# Does this support arm based processors

Tags: robotic-arm, linux

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm considering using a raspberry pie for this and i was wondering if the software supports arm based processors?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35665/does-this-support-arm-based-processors/) by [Nickfost](https://answers.ros.org/users/2538/nickfost/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-06-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-06-04**:
May I know how many bit is your raspberry pie? 8 or 16?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, ROS runs on ARM-based systems in principle, even if you have to do quite a bit more manual installation/configuration stuff compared to the package-based install on Ubuntu.
For the Raspberry Pi see [this Q/A](http://answers.ros.org/question/34501/how-to-setting-up-ros-on-raspberrypi/) and [this tutorial website that came out of it](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROSberryPi/Setting%20up%20ROS%20on%20RaspberryPi).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1